# потеря символов (+) из кук

Tags: php, cookie

доброго времени суток.
в браузере есть куки такого содержимого:

```
[{"name":"name","value":"rt"},{"name":"email","value":"+fw++e@Feds+.tt"},{"name":"cust-phone","value":"+7 (888) 888-88-88"}]
```

при отправке запроса серверу в заголовках куки имеют нормальный вид. но в глобальный массив символы "+" не попадают, вместо них пробел " "

```
mail("mymail@gmail.com", "vrdmp", print_r($_COOKIE["arr_inp"], true));
```

присылает такой вид:

```
[{"name":"name","value":"rt"},{"name":"email","value":" fw  e@Feds .tt"},{"name":"cust-phone","value":" 7 (888) 888-88-88"}]
```

я предполагаю что это настройка сервера, но можно ли на это влиять прямо в коде? если нет, то что надо менять в конфиге сервера что бы получить куки в неизменном виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

при отправке данных необходимо строку закодировать ([URL-кодирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL))

php (используется функция [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)):

```
urlencode($phone);
```

js ([encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)):

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('+791112233444'));
```

Comment: спасибо, это помогло, но не опечатка ли здесь? `при отправке данных необходимо строку декодировать`, может закодировать? и ещё, можно ли настроить это поведение на уровне сервера?

Comment: Да, опечатался, спасибо, что заметили. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: *можно ли настроить это поведение на уровне сервера?* Вы хотите автоматически уже принимать + не кодируя его?

Comment: не то что бы, впервые столкнулся с этой проблемой, для общих знаний хотелось бы знать возможно ли это настроить или всегда в куках надо хранить кодированные символы

Comment: если вы про куки то да. Смотрите, куки хранятся на машине клиента, как их получить? При загрузке страницы они передаются get запросе. А что бы передать запрос его надо закодировать в любом случае

Comment: если post отправлять данные, то кодировать ничего не надо. Но тогда вы явно должны передавать данные допустим аяксом

Comment: как вариант, вы можете хранить номер без "+", а просто добавлять его когда выбираете данные

Comment: лучше все таки куки всегда хранить кодированными, "+" не всегда может встретиться только в телефоне, а ля унификация. благодарю за ответ и коментарии